# Neo4j Docs provide an example with the incorrect syntax. Trying to use COUNT with the WITH statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm going through the neo4j docs studying cypher's syntax
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#cypher-subquery-expressions

and about half way down the page is this example:

```
MATCH (person:Person)
WHERE COUNT {
    WITH "Ozzy" AS dogName
    MATCH (person)-[:HAS_DOG]->(d:Dog)
    WHERE d.name = dogName
} = 1
RETURN person.name AS name
```

and now I want to convert it to run in my sample graph which as nodes PLAYER and TEAM, and relationship PLAYED_AGAINST.  My converted query is this:

```
MATCH (p:PLAYER)
WHERE COUNT {
    WITH "Brooklyn Nets" AS teamName
    MATCH (p)-[:PLAYED_AGAINST]->(t:TEAM)
    WHERE t.name = teamName
} = 1
RETURN p.name AS name
```

which I think matches neo4j's docs exactly, however, I'm getting this error:

> Invalid input 'WITH': expected "(", "allShortestPaths" or
> "shortestPath" (line 3, column 5 (offset: 35)) "    WITH "Brooklyn
> Nets" AS teamName"
> ^

which actually looks like this:
[image]

1. Are the docs incorrect or am I missing something?
2. What would the correct syntax be for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason you are getting this error is that you are not using of the later version of Neo4j. Probably all version of Neo4j v5 work with this syntax, and perhaps some of the later versions of v4, but probably not many. I have both of these queries and they work in Neo4j v5.5.0

Comment: I'm using version 5.1.0.  I executed this to get the version number:  

CALL dbms.components()
YIELD versions
RETURN versions

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

Although the [COUNT subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#count-subqueries) expression was [introduced in neo4j 5.0](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#_new_features_2), it did not support a `WITH` clause in the subquery until version 5.3 (verified by testing).

This query should work for you, instead (there was no good reason for using the `WITH` in the first place):

```
MATCH (p:PLAYER)
WHERE COUNT {
    MATCH (p)-[:PLAYED_AGAINST]->(t:TEAM)
    WHERE t.name = "Brooklyn Nets"
} = 1
RETURN p.name AS name
```

Comment: Thanks, but no.   I'm using version 5.1.0. I executed this to get the version number: CALL dbms.components() YIELD versions RETURN versions